# Reading and writing files in API 30 (Android 11) in Kivy

Tags: python, android, permissions, kivy

I am code an app in Python/Kivy (recently used version 1.11.1, now 2.0.0). The year before last, Android 10 was released (aka Andoid Q, api 29), in 2020 Android 11 was released (aka Android R, api 30). Starting from these versions, Google has set restrictions on reading and writing files, so as you know now files can be read or written only after getting certain permissions, in dedicated places, and in a certain sequence (now we need to use the application's personal folder, where the app can of course "make garbage", and from public directories only in those related to ScopedStorage for devices with API >= 29). We can't work freely with files in */storage/emulated/0* and */sdcard*.

Just what sequence I really cannot understand. I reviewed a lot of examples, but now it seems that nobody really writes apps where it is necessary to provide users with public access to their project files (share or open them). I don't want to think that kivy was created only for hello world, root-checkers, games, and other apps, which can easily get by with the internal folder. Besides api 30 just ordered the developers to move applications to ScopedStorage. It seems to me that I'm just missing something.

The manifest contains both **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** and **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**.
I'm building on *Ubuntu 18 / buildozer*, everything is going fine. But anyway when trying to get data from a file, an error **13 Permission denied**.

From the best information I've found:
https://github.com/niharika2810/ScopedStorageDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/scopedstorage/activities/MainActivity.kt
https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/request-file.html
It seems that the *python-for-android* wrapper does not take into account the latest changes from api 30, which can be used so easily in android studio?
I myself try to reach the files data using pyjnius. Like I convert java code to python, the app gets the permissions, and as a result, when I try to read the file, it still show me **Permission denied**.

**The question is:** How can I get data from a text file for API 30 in the bundle **python-kivy-p4a-jnius** so that the app does not give the *#13 Permission denied* error?

Part of my code (mostly used code from the kivy forums where one man in the best way (I think) structured using *callback* for *startActivityForResult* under python/kivy):

at the beginning of main.py:

```
if platform == 'android':
    from kivy.logger import Logger
    from kivy.clock import Clock

    from jnius import autoclass
    from jnius import cast

    from android import activity
    from android.permissions import Permission, request_permissions, check_permission

    Activity = autoclass('android.app.Activity')
    PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
    Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
    Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')
    File = autoclass('java.io.File')
    Env = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
    
    MediaStore_Images_Media_DATA = "_data"  # Value of MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA

    # Custom request codes
    RESULT_LOAD_DOC = 1

    def permissions_callback(permissions, results):
        print('inside permissions_callback')
        if all([res for res in results]):
            print('Got all permissions')
            permissions_granted = True
        else:
            print('Did not get all permissions')
    
    def get_permissions():
        request_permissions([
            Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Permission.INTERNET],
            permissions_callback)
    
    def user_select_doc(callback):
        """Open File chooser and call callback with absolute filepath of document user selected.
        None if user canceled.
        """
        
        currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
        context = cast('android.content.ContextWrapper', currentActivity.getApplicationContext())
        file_p = cast('java.io.File', context.getExternalFilesDir(Env.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS))
        
        def on_activity_result(request_code, result_code, intent):
            if request_code != RESULT_LOAD_DOC:
                Logger.warning('user_select_doc: ignoring activity result that was not RESULT_LOAD_DOC')
                return

            if result_code == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: callback(None), 0)
                return

            if result_code != Activity.RESULT_OK:
                # This may just go into the void...
                raise NotImplementedError('Unknown result_code "{}"'.format(result_code))

            selectedFile = intent.getData();  # Uri
            filePathColumn = [MediaStore_Images_Media_DATA]; # String[]
            # Cursor
            cursor = currentActivity.getContentResolver().query(selectedFile, filePathColumn, None, None, None)
            cursor.moveToFirst()

            # int
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            # String
            docPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            Logger.info('android_ui: user_select_doc() selected %s', docPath)

            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: callback(docPath), 0)
        
        activity.bind(on_activity_result = on_activity_result)
        
        intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.setType("*/*")
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, False)
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        
        # currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
        # chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, 'Select TXT')
        # currentActivity.startActivityForResult(chooser, RESULT_LOAD_DOC)
        currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_DOC)

    def load(filename):
        with io.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = None
            
            try:
                data = json.load(file)
            except:
                print('JSON not loaded')
                return False
```

Further for some button:

```
def on_load(self, button):
    if platform == 'android':
        if check_permission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") \
        and check_permission("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") \
        and check_permission("android.permission.INTERNET"):
        # if permissions_granted:   # variant
            user_select_doc(load)
        else:
            get_permissions()
```

Comment: `But anyway when trying to get data from a file,` What is full path of file? And how landed that file there? Why dont you start with trying to write a file somewhere?

Comment: `How can I get data from a text file` How did the user pick that file?

Comment: Do not use the .DATA column to get a file path for that uri. Always a bad habit but .DATA is useless on Android 11. Instead use the uri directly to open an inputstream and then read from it. No permissions needed at all.

Comment: @blackapps My app will need to work on both desktop and android. For example, a user was working on a project on a desktop and wrote the project to a *project.json*. He moved this file to his smartphone. For example to public folder **/storage/emulated/0/Documents/project.json** (it is from it that I am trying to read the file). Now the android app should open/pick this file and parse the project.
About inputstream in kivy/android I don't know much. How to create an inputstream using kivy/p4a/jnius(???) ? I have not found such information. Thanks for any answer  
PS: Sorry for english

Comment: @blackapps I understand the base structure of android. But I don't know much about the command structure of the android studio (about .DATA). If I knew, I probably would not use kivy)

Comment: `currentActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData());`

Comment: @blackapps Thanks a lot, I will try.    PS: Can I somehow improve the reputation of your post? Not yet fully familiar with the stackoverflow

Comment: @blackapps `Do not use the .DATA column to get a file path for that uri. Always a bad habit but .DATA is useless on Android 11` See the second last comment, before it was marked as fixed (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151407044) - `For existing Media Store entries if the file exists on disk DATA column will have a valid file path, which can be used with java File api or NDK library (fopen etc)`

Comment: Please describe a scenario where there are existing media store values and the .DATA column has a file path on an Android 11 device.

Comment: @blackapps `a scenario where there are existing media store values` I'm not sure what you mean with this. `and the .DATA column has a file path` every file that is available on the disk has a `_data` column entry. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#data-column

Comment: @blackapps The reading problem seems to be resolved. I was not quite aware of what ContentResolver is rich in. Thank you for the tip and a nice kick.  
Using **currentActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData())** I was able to get the binary data of the selected file and now I can do whatever I want with this data.<br>But now I am stuck with writing to a file. I am confused how can I create a **completely new uri**? and write for example some binary data to it? it is through python and android 10-11

Comment: @blackapps ...after creating a *file* of *autoclass('java.io.File')* I do *uri = Uri.fromFile(file)* of *autoclass('android.net.Uri')*. But **fos = currentActivity.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri, "wt")** and then *fos.write(file)*, *fos.flush()*, *fos.close()* don't work %)

Answer (score 0):

The reading problem seems to be resolved. I was not quite aware of what ContentResolver is rich in. Thanks to **blackapps** for the hint in which direction to look.
Using **currentActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData())** I was able to get the binary data of the selected file and now I can do whatever I want with this data.
Thus, at the moment my **reading solution** (in addition to the code above) is:

```
# From the received Uri I am getting a data stream
selectedUri = intent.getData()
docStream = currentActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedUri)

# I get an int array from the stream
ints = []
intVal = docStream.read()

while intVal != -1:
    ints.append(intVal)
    intVal = docStream.read()

# And convert the array to bytes and pass it to the callback function
docBytes = bytes(b % 256 for b in ints)
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: callback(docBytes), 0)
```

The **solution for saving files** (back to the same file or via "save as") turned out to be a little more confusing for me. Not without **FileDescriptor**. Here is the function to call the android save window (in essence, only the intent changes):

```
def android_dialog_save_doc(save_callback):
    currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
    
    def on_activity_save(request_code, result_code, intent):
        if request_code != RESULT_SAVE_DOC:
            Logger.warning('android_dialog_save_doc: ignoring activity result that was not RESULT_SAVE_DOC')
            return
        
        if result_code == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: save_callback(None), 0)
            return
        
        if result_code != Activity.RESULT_OK:
            # This may just go into the void...
            raise NotImplementedError('Unknown result_code "{}"'.format(result_code))
        
        selectedUri = intent.getData()                  # Uri
        filePathColumn = [MediaStore_Images_Media_DATA] # String
        
        # Cursor
        cursor = currentActivity.getContentResolver().query(selectedUri, filePathColumn, None, None, None)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        
        # If you need to get the document path, but I used selectedUri.getPath()
        # columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])  # int
        # docPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)                 # String
        cursor.close()
        Logger.info('android_ui: android_dialog_save_doc() selected %s', selectedUri.getPath())
        
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: save_callback(selectedUri), 0)
    
    activity.bind(on_activity_result = on_activity_save)
    
    # Here's another Intent in contrast to get the file
    intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    intent.setType('*/*')
    
    currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SAVE_DOC)
```

Callback function passed as **android_dialog_save_doc(android_do_saving)**:

```
def android_do_saving(uri):
    currentActivity = cast('android.app.Activity', PythonActivity.mActivity)
    
    # Just some function that returns binary data from somewhere to write to uri
    bytedata = get_bytes()
    
    if bytedata != None:
        try:
            # For writing, it is important to get ParcelFileDescriptor from ContentResolver ...
            pfd = currentActivity.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w")
            
            # ... because from ParcelFileDescriptor you need to use getFileDescriptor() function,
            # which will allow us to create a FileOutputStream (and not a regular OutputStream), ...
            fos = FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor())
            
            # ... because FileOutputStream can access the OutputStream channel,
            fos_ch = fos.getChannel()
            
            # ... so that after writing data to a file ...
            fos.write(bytedata)
            
            # ... this channel was able to cut off extra bytes if the number of newly written bytes was less than in the file being rewritten.
            fos_ch.truncate(len(bytedata))
            
            fos.close()
            
            # I save the uri in case of a quick overwrite, so you do not open every time the android file selection window
            openedUri = uri
            
            print('Saving bytedata succeeded.')
        except:
            print('Saving bytedata failed.')
```

Comment: you saved and got that file path?

Comment: @koushik yes I did. I used "selectedUri.getPath()". But the path can be obtained using "docPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)" (see above). But the strings of these uris will be different, as far as I remember, and it's not easy to load a file by just uri string in API 30.

Comment: everything is good but when getting array from stream is super slow taking so much to convert into array because the file is 15 - 20 MB data is there any after solution for that