# Python Kivy Android API 30 reading txt file

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to get text of textfile from the Android Storage, but I can't.
I used usually:

```
def show_selection(self, chooser, selection,*args):
    print(selection)

    # for cycle because selection variable is tuple (get str)
    for i in selection:
       print(i) #i is fullpath to selected file

    f = open(i, "r") #permission denied error here
    eng_text = f.read()
    print(eng_text)

def file_manager_open(self, *args):

   result = primary_external_storage_path()

   print(result)
   #using native filechooser from plyer library
   file_choose = filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.show_selection)
```

And gets Permission denied error. I know about changes in Android API 30, I found the same problem and solution: [Reading and writing files in API 30 (Android 11) in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65599482/reading-and-writing-files-in-api-30-android-11-in-kivy)

But I don't understand how to integrate that to my code, I just need simple example.

Comment: Why dont you use a full path?

Comment: Mention full path please.

Comment: I'm used that, it's just minimum example code*

Comment: my full paths is: /storage/emulated/0/1.txt

Comment: Minimum example code? What would that be? Please put full path in your code.

Comment: Okay, I'm fixed code in my question with details.

Comment: We cannot see a full path. We do not know what you do or where you are after.

Comment: I'm just trying to read the contents of a file on Android API 30, the path to the file I wrote in the comment above...

Comment: file_choose variable gets selected file path like tuple, for cycle used to take out of the tuple string value, that string value is /storage/emulated/0/1.txt (for example)

Comment: Dont know what you mean with tuple. And i think that you posted too much irrelevant code. All that you had to post was `f = open("/storage/emulated/0/1.txt", "r")` and everybody would have known what you were doing.

Comment: Problem not in the code, problem in Android API 30 with updated permission rules